# KeyEvent.VK_ + int i, output with Bot possible?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, keyevent

Since yesterday, im working on a Program, that saves 1 password permanently, so its only for 1 time use. The saved password shall be printed by keyboard output later, thats why I thought, id start with an Array. Many people in other questions told me, that they would use ObjectArray or something like that. I am quite new to Java, thats why I would appreciate help. By the way, if you suggest something, id appreciate it, if its a bit more in depth.
Here is the Code.

```
Robot bot = new Robot();
BufferedReader dmc = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

System.out.println("How many digits has your Password?");
String digit = dmc.readLine();
int d = Integer.parseInt(digit);
String[] password = new String[d];
System.out.println("Please enter your Password in single letters.");

int i = 0;
while (password[d - 1] == null) {
    password[i] = dmc.readLine();
    i++;
}

int j = 0;
while(j != d){
    password[j] = "KeyEvent.VK_" + password[j];
    j++;
}
```

poorly this doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid storing passwords in Strings because of security reasons. You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291/why-is-char-preferred-over-string-for-passwords-in-java)  .

```
BufferedReader dmc = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

System.out.println("How many digits has your Password?");
String digit = dmc.readLine();
int d = Integer.parseInt(digit);
char[] password = new char[d];
System.out.println("Please enter your Password in single letters.");

dmc.read(password);

Stream.of(password).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Thanks, that made it a bit easier, but I still cant print the password as keyboard output, as it is System.out.println, not KeyEvent.

Comment: What do you mean by "keyboard output" . Keyboard is a input device.

Comment: I mean, that with System.out.println, you only write in the command section, meaning it has no real effect, if you want to write something on another thread. For example, I have this code fully compiled and start a Program that needs an Password input. With System.out.Println it doesnt write anything, since its a System output. With a KeyEvent, it simulates a Keyboard input, so it writes something. 

I admit with "Keyboard output" its a bit confusing and wrong :D